# Fetching items while preserving order of ordered relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have the following (simplified) data model:

[image]
[image]

And the following fetch request:

```
static func fetchRequestForItems(fromListWithName name: String) -> FetchRequest?  {

let request = Item.sortedFetchRequest

    request?.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K.%K like %@", #keyPath(Item.lists), #keyPath(ItemList.name), name)
    request?.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "items", ascending: true)]

    return request
}
```

Called like:

```
let request = Item.fetchRequestForItems(fromListWithName: "Favorites")!
let result = try! persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
```

What I’m trying to achieve is fetching `Item`s in the order that they have been added to `ItemList`s

However I’m currently getting this error:

`caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[<Item 0x600003b7ff20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Item is not key value coding-compliant for the key "items"."`

Does anyone know how to achieve fetching the correctly ordered items without getting errors?

**Update**

Some more background information on why I am performing creating a `NSFetchRequest<Item>` instead of  `NSFetchRequest<ItemList>`. The reason for this is that I’m hoping to use a fetched results controller of type `NSFetchedResultsController<Item>`  and more importantly it’s delegate method `func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)` which should give me indexPath in the order that’s the same as the .items of `ItemList` .

Comment: You are fetching on `Item`. So this causes the crash with the error: `[NSSortDescriptor(key: "items", ascending: true)]`. It's `ItemList` that has a `items` property, not `Item`.

Comment: Why fetch the `Items` - why not fetch the relevant `ItemList`, and use its `items` property, which will be ordered correctly?

Comment: @pbasdf this is because I'm aiming for the use this FetchRequest as part of a FetchedResultsController. Without fetching Items, I'm afraid I cannot leverage the `controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)` method of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` because there would only be one indexPath a query resulting in the same items.

Comment: @Larme I've tried the opposite as well, when I do this: I get the same error but then for the `item` key: `caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[<Item 0x6000011d71b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Item is not key value coding-compliant for the key "item"."`

Comment: What did you try exactly in the opposed case? Because it seems that you still performed the request on Item and not ItemList.

Comment: @Larme I changed the key from `items` to `item`. I've added an **Update** to explain why.

Comment: Relation is many to many, so I don't know how the order is supposed to be but maybe with `request?.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lists", ascending: true)] or `request?.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lists.items", ascending: true)]`

Comment: @Larme that seemed promising, but unfortunately resulted in `caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[__NSOrderedSetI compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000012abd20"`

Comment: Imagine you have two ordered sets (1,2) and (2,1). Which on is the first? Which one is the second? There is no comparison method in them I guess. That's the issue. You can't really order them by order of the `lists.items`

Comment: I don't like the outcome but am happy with your answer, I see your point is valid and I'd accept this as the answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to achieve this, you should create an intermediate entity to replace the many-many relationship.  The new entity should have an attribute to represent the required order, and to-one relationships to Item and ItemList (each with a to-many inverse).